# onBind() and onServiceConnected() are not called after bindService() in onCreate()

Tags: android, service

I followed the tutorial on Google's developer's documentation site for Services and might have missed something. I was able to start and stop the Service correctly, but now that I am trying to bind to the Service, I am getting a NullPointerException because onBind() and onServiceConnected() are not called after bindService(). I have read over 10 questions on StackOverflow and none of them have helped.

Part of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.waveplayer">
    <application
        <service android:name="com.example.waveplayer.ServiceMain"
            android:exported="false"
            android:description="@string/service_description"
            android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
</manifest>
```

The code used to start the service on OnCreate():

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceMain.class);
            startService(intent);
        getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

 private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            ServiceMain.ServiceMainBinder binder = (ServiceMain.ServiceMainBinder) service;
            serviceMain = binder.getService();
            serviceMainBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            serviceMainBound = false;
        }
    };
```

And my service code:

```
    private Looper serviceMainLooper;

    private ServiceMainHandler serviceMainHandler;

    private final IBinder serviceMainBinder = new ServiceMainBinder();

    private final class ServiceMainHandler extends Handler {

        public ServiceMainHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceMainStartArguments",
                Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();
        serviceMainLooper = thread.getLooper();
        serviceMainHandler = new ServiceMainHandler(serviceMainLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
        // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
        Message msg = serviceMainHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        serviceMainHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceMain.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        String CHANNEL_ID = "ServiceMain";
        RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_song_pane);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        startForeground(CHANNEL_ID.hashCode(), builder.build());
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public class ServiceMainBinder extends Binder {
        ServiceMain getService() {
            return ServiceMain.this;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return serviceMainBinder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        saveFile();
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Is service actually starting and calling its `onBind`?

Comment: No. The Service isn't even starting now. I had it starting before.

Comment: Ok, so the Service doesn't start until after onStart(). Where am I supposed to bind to the Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Service isn't created until the UI thread is clear of code from the Activity, therefore I couldn't access it until after the `onStart()` method of my Activity. That is what the `onServiceConnected()` callback method is for. At that point the Service has been created and the Activity has access to the Service.